# How to identify a code in file name and open that file in a folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with templates to update for this month. One of the tasks is to find the report for a specific template (located in another folder), open it, go to a tab, copy the content and paste to another tab in the template.

In cell A3 of each template, there is a BU code that is in the file name of the report (the file is named as region_BU code_XXXXXXXXXXX, where the "X" can be any).

I am trying to find the BU code in the file name and open that file.

The code opened one file, but nothing was copied and pasted.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set ff = fso.getfolder("C:\Users\Win_1\summary\test")
    
    For Each file In ff.Files
    
        Workbooks.Open file
        Set wbk2 = ActiveWorkbook
        Sheets("Summary").Select
    
        rngY = Range("A3").Value
    
        Dim fname As Variant
        Dim myFile As String
    
        myPath = "C:\Users\Win_1\MLA\reports"
        fname = Dir(myPath & "*rngY*")
    
        If fname <> "" Then

            Workbooks.Open (myPath & fname)
            Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
            Sheets("Assumptions Report").Cells.Select
            Selection.Copy
            wbk2.Activate
            Sheets("3-22").Select
            Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            wbk1.Activate
            Sheets("New Report").Range("D10").Select
            Selection.Copy
            wbk2.Activate
            Sheets("Summary").Select
            Dim rFound As Range
            Set rFound = Range("A10:A100").Find(Format("44651", "mmm-yy"), , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False, False)
            
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then rFound.Select
    
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            wbk1.Activate
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.Close

        End If

        wbk2.Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: @braX did you help with the codes or just the format of the codes?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a couple of tweaks to your code, below (See the comments)

```vba
Sub Macro1()
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set ff = fso.getfolder("C:\Users\Win_1\summary\test")
    
    For Each file In ff.Files
        Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(file) 'this is better than relying on Activeworkbook once you've opened the file.
        wbk2.Sheets("Summary").Select
    
        rngY = Range("A3").Value
    
        Dim fname As Variant
        Dim myFile As String
    
        myPath = "C:\Users\Win_1\MLA\reports"
        fname = Dir(myPath & "*" & rngY& "*")
    
        If fname <> "" Then

            Set wbk1 =  Workbooks.Open(myPath & fname)
            wbk1.Sheets("Assumptions Report").Cells.Copy 'avoid using Select wherever possible.
            wbk2.Activate
            Sheets("3-22").Activate
            Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            wbk1.Activate
            Sheets("New Report").Range("D10").Copy
            wbk2.Activate
            Sheets("Summary").Activate
            Dim rFound As Range
            Set rFound = Range("A10:A100").Find(Format("44651", "mmm-yy"), , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False, False)
            
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then 
                  rFound.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If
            wbk1.Save
            wbk1.Close

        End If

        wbk2.Save
        wbk2.Close
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @spencer Thank you very much! there is a syntax error with this line fname = Dir(myPath & "*" & rngY& "*").

Comment: what do the variables `myPath` and `rngY` evaluate to at point of throwing the error?

Comment: Possibly `myPath` should have a backslash at the end of it, unless `rngY` contains a backslash at the start?

Comment: Also, if anyone else is to debug your code in future, it would be a lot simpler to change the name of your variable `rngY` to `strY` or similar, as the prefix 'rng' is generally used for Range variables and this variable is storing a value, not a range.

Comment: that's a good idea. I will keep that in mind. No rngY doesn't contain backslash. let me try your comments. Thank you!